# Parsing my data to search the csv array

Tags: php, arrays, html, csv, foreach

I know the answer might be easy but struggling to get this to work. I have the below code

```
}

$csv = array();

// Open File with error handler
if (($file = fopen('./csv/file.csv', 'r')) === false) {
     throw new Exception('There was an error loading the CSV file.');
     }

  else {
       while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000)) !== false) {
       $csv[] = $line;}

fclose($file);}




if (isset($_GET['names'])) {
$name = $_GET['names'];


 $results = array();

 foreach($csv as $curr) {
 $Data = explode(',',$curr['1']);
 if(in_array($names,$Data)
    $results[] = $curr;
 }
      } else {

 ...... Blah blah blah

?>
```

So what im trying to do is parse the data from the url with get and search the csv array to find matching string in each key and array[1] (its a 2 column csv file), if the name matches it gets the value from csv[0] and store in array so i can print it out to screen. Lost as im not getting a matching string in my arrays. any help where im going wrong?

An example of the Csv file:

```
 Charlie and the chocolate factory, Ronald Dahl
 Hunger games, Suzanne Collins
 ect
```

So what i want to do is parse the data from the url ?name=Suzanne,%20Collins to search my csv array. So it picks all the books by suzanne collins and places the value in my array.

Comment: As your using `fgetcsv` you probably don't need to do `$Data = explode(',',$curr['1']);`.  It would also be helpful if you included a line or two from your CSV file in your question.

Comment: Hey Nigel, i have been looking using the below code as another way:

     $books = array_keys($csv[1], $name1);

to filter out the books that much the string but it isnt parsing the value to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to stick with as much of your code as I can, the main change is in the loop which looks for the authors.  As I mentioned, the `fgetcsv` already splits the fields down, but as there may be spaces around the name (as in your example) I've used `trim` in the test to ensure I'm not missing anyone.

```
// Open File with error handler
if (($file = fopen('./books.csv', 'r')) === false) {
    throw new Exception('There was an error loading the CSV file.');
}

$books = array();
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
    $books[] = $line;
}
fclose($file);

if (isset($_GET['names'])) {
    $name = $_GET['names'];

    $results = array();

    foreach($books as $book) {
        if( $name == trim($book[1]))  {
            $results[] = $book;
        }
    }

    print_r($results);
}
```

(Note that I have changed the file name for my test purposes, so don't forget to change this)